# Unexpected error response from GitHub API 422 when attempting to create issue

Tags: go, github-api

When posting an issue to GitHub API V3 I am getting an unexpected response. Namely 422 Unprocessable Entity. However the detail of the error is for the Search endpoint rather that the POST create endpoint.
{"message":"Validation Failed","errors":[{"resource":"Search","field":"q","code":"missing"}],"documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/search"}

My instinct is that I have messed up the json but it is pretty simple and I can't see the issue.
I have tried various solutions posted here and elsewhere but not found what I am doing wrong. This is a coding exercise rather than anything intended for production but driving me mildly insane.

- Tested in Debug what the Request body is just before being posted.
  {"title":"Hello World","body":"dfsdfsdf\n"}
- Tried removing the body as it is optional, same issue.
- Tested in Debug that request is of type POST
- Tested in Debug that authorization header is correct.
- Removed authorization key and received 401 as expected.

The posting function:

```
func CreateIssue (issue *NewIssue) (*IssueDetailsResult, error){
issueJson, err := json.Marshal(issue)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", github.IssuesURL, bytes.NewBuffer(issueJson))
req.Header.Set("Authorization", "token "+os.Getenv("UPGITUSER"))
req.Header.Set( "Content-Type", "application/json")
client := &http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusCreated {
    bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    body := string(bodyBytes)
    resp.Body.Close()
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("create issue failed:%s", resp.Status + "\ntext: " + body)
}
var result IssueDetailsResult
if err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&result); err != nil {
    resp.Body.Close()
    return nil, err
}
resp.Body.Close()
return &result, nil
```

}

Would expect 201 from GitHubAPI.

Comment: Are you certain your `github.IssuesURL` value is pointing to the right endpoint? From the example code we can't tell if it has the correct value.

Comment: Before sending the request try using https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpRequestOut to confirm that everything is as it should be. (don't forget to pass in true as the second argument to see the body as well)

Comment: const IssuesURL = "https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/issues"  substituting owner and repo appropriately.

Comment: POST /search/issues HTTP/1.1
Host: api.github.com
Authorization: token MYTOKEN
Content-Type: application/json

{"title":"Hello World","body":"dsddsd \n"}

Comment: Looks like the endpoint is wrong thank you for the hint about DumpRequest

Comment: No idea how that is happening there is literally only one url in the entire app but I will track it down.

Comment: @mkopriva Do you want to post an answer with the DumpRequest hint so I can mark it as the answer.  Hints to me in real life.  Don't create projects called github and leave them compiled in the src directory.   The URL was being pulled from that go package not the existing one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is a strong indicator that the request is being sent to the wrong endpoint.

You can use `net/http/httputil`'s [DumpRequestOut](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpRequestOut) to inspect the requests you are about to send and to ensure that they are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Using the DumpRequestOut method above was able to determine the URL being called was incorrect.  The code uses github.IssuesURL, which is in fact a separate package previously written and left in my src directory.  Removing the github. solves the issue.  Many thanks.